# Play evolution escaping table names

Tags: postgresql, playframework, ebean, playframework-evolutions

I've got Play!Framework running with `jdbc` and `Postgresql` as database. I'd like to enable evolutions for development usage.

Play doesn't seem to automatically escape table names. For instance, when creating a table called `user`, I can't seem to automatically create a table because `user` is a reserved word in SQL.

Play generates an evolution like this:

```
# --- Rev:1,Ups - 4fb5e22
create table user (
id                        bigserial not null,
name                      varchar(255),
constraint pk_user primary key (id));
```

Is there any way to automatically escape table names?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it possible. You can try to use some of the common escaping

like Hibernate:

```
@Table(name="`user`")
```

like JPA2:

```
@Table(name="\"user\"")
```

For myself - I never use reserved words for the naming. You always will fall with this, always. so just use different table name, even if you do not want to change the class name itself, annotate it with the different table name:

```
@Table(name="user_table")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'automatically'. Evolutions are basically sql commands submitted to the database, so however postgresql escapes identified names should also be valid syntax in your evolutions. I'm no postgresql expert, but I believe double quotes will do what you are after :

```
create table "user" (
  id bigserial not null,
  name varchar(255),
constraint pk_user primary key (id));
```